# Excel VBA to synchronize with SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I have downloaded the add ins from https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=9345 to synchronize the data between Excel table and SharePoint list. How could I, by using VBA code, to run the "Synchronize with SharePoint" operation instead of click it manually?

---

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/59199

Comment: The operation of "ListObject.UpdateChanges" doesn't work for Excel version later than 2003 :( how could I work around with this?

Comment: That question deserves a question of its own honestly